# Weird error when attempting to input a vector of doubles

Tags: c++

I have big problems with entering the participants times.

In the terminal it should look like:

```
Enter participants:
Kalle Svensson Glommen IK
Anna Nilsson Glommen IK
Per-Erik Jonsson Tuna OK
DONE
Times Kalle: 12.34 10.01 -1.00
Times Anna: 8.05 9.57 10.00 12.34 -1.00
Times Per-Erik: 10.44 -1.00
 Surname   First name     Club: Times
==========================================
 Nilsson Anna Glommen IK: 8.05 9.57 10.00 12.34
 Svensson Kalle Glommen IK: 10.01 12.34
 Jonsson Per-Erik Tuna OK: 10.44
```

---

This is my code:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Runner_Type
{
  string first_name;
  string surname;
  string club;
  string club_last;
  vector<double> time;
  
};

using Many_Runners_Type = vector<Runner_Type>;


void print(Runner_Type const & runner)

{
  cout << setw(9) << runner.surname << setw(10) << runner.first_name << setw(13) << runner.club << setw(3) << runner.club_last;

}


void print(Many_Runners_Type const & many_runners)
{
  for (Runner_Type const & runners : many_runners)
    {      
      print(runners);
      cout << endl;
    }
}


int main()
  
{
  Runner_Type runner {};
  Many_Runners_Type many_runners {};
  string name {};
  int counter {};
  double tid {};



  cout << "Enter participants: " << endl;

  while (true)
    
    {
      cin >> name;

      counter++;

      if (name == "DONE")

    {
      break;
    }

      runner.first_name = name;

      cin >> runner.surname >> runner.club >> runner.club_last;
      many_runners.push_back(runner);
      
    }

  for (int i {}; i < counter; ++i)
    {
      cout << "Times " << many_runners.at(i).first_name << ": ";

      while (tid != -1.0)
    {
      cin >> tid;
      runner.time.push_back(tid);
    }

    }

  cout << "Surname" << setw(11) << "First name" << setw(23) << "Club: Times" << endl;
  cout << "==========================================" << endl;


  print(many_runners);
  cout << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

---

I can enter the names of the participants but when I try to enter the times it wont work. I tried doing a loop that breaks out of the loop if the input is -1.0.

This is how my terminal looks like:

```
Enter participants: 
Cebu Jonsson FC Barcelona
DONE
Times Cebu: 12.12 14.12 -1 

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why am I getting this error? My program does comply but when I run it, type the times and end with a "-1" I get this weird error. Help is greatly appreicated

Comment: details matter. Please post your actual code. The code you did post does not compile

Comment: don't keep track of a vectors size manually, thats a recipe for bugs. Use its `size()` method

Comment: I updated it, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: So I just put runner.size() in my loop?

Comment: not sure if that alone fixes your code. I don't understand why you use a `vector<Runner_Type>;` but then read times into the member of a seperate `Runner_Type runner {};`. Maybe thats what you want, but it doesnt look right

Comment: @Cebu *So I just put runner.size() in my loop?* -- A vector knows its size already, without error, and without miscounting.  That is achieved by calling `size()`.  Having unnecessary, extraneous variables tracking the size will open you up for bugs.  If the vector is resized in any way, and you rely on this extra variable, the real size and this "fake" size will go out-of-synch, causing errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I get errors when I try to do runner.size()

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `size()`.  That's proof that your logic was flawed using the fake size variable.  That error is proof you were going out-of-bounds, as an exception is thrown when you do so.

Comment: `many_runners.at(i)` -- This is the only place you call `at()`, and this is where the exception must have been thrown.  Obviously (and if you read the message carefully), `i` is out-of-bounds.  The error is telling you that `many_runners` has no index `1` available -- it's out of bounds.   Print out the `size()` of the `many_runners` vector before you go into that loop.

Answer (score 0):

You increment `counter` one time too many, i.e. when `DONE` is entered you should not increment. So you read past the end of the vector.
As suggested in the comments, I would leave out the counter and query the vector about its `.size()`.

Comment: So I guess I just need to change counter in my loop to runner.size() ?

Comment: Yes, in the ``for`` loop . You can remove the variable ``counter`` from the code completely when you do that.

Comment: I get errors when I try to do runner.size()

Comment: You have to call ``.size()`` on the vector. The vector is called ``many_runners`` , not``runner``.